# stdin/stdout names in BASH?

Tags: command-line, io-redirection

I have a program that takes a `-o log_file` option, which writes extra data to `log_file`.

Is there any way for me to redirect that to stdout?

i.e. is there a "special name" for stdout that can be used as a file name, like `CONOUT$` on Windows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Usually, programs write automatically to stdout if you don't specify a `-o` option.
In the case you must go through the `-o` option, you can use `-o /dev/stdout`.

Comment: Ahhh `/dev/stdout` is exactly what I needed. Thank you!! :)

Comment: And I won't call that "redirection" but just "direction" :-)

Comment: Lol whatever you say :)